# Most Frequent words in each row

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I am trying to find the most frequent words, in each row of a tokenized Dataframe as follows:

```
print(df.tokenized_sents)

['apple', 'inc.', 'aapl', 'reported', 'fourth', 'consecutive', 'quarter', 'record', 'revenue', 'profit', 'combination', 'higher', 'iphone', 'prices', 'strong', 'app-store', 'sales', 'propelled', 'technology', 'giant', 'best', 'year', 'ever', 'revenue', 'three', 'months', 'ended', 'sept.']

['brussels', 'apple', 'inc.', 'aapl', '-.', 'chief', 'executive', 'tim', 'cook', 'issued', 'tech', 'giants', 'strongest', 'call', 'yet', 'u.s.-wide', 'data-protection', 'regulation', 'saying', 'individuals', 'personal', 'information', 'been', 'weaponized', 'mr.', 'cooks', 'call', 'came', 'sharply', 'worded', 'speech', 'before', 'p…']

...

wrds = []
for i in range(0, len(df) ):

    wrds.append( Counter(df["tokenized_sents"][i]).most_common(5) )
```

But it reports a list as:

```
print(wrds)

[('revenue', 2), ('apple', 1), ('inc.', 1), ('aapl', 1), ('reported', 1)]
...
```

I would like to create the following dataframe instead;

```
print(final_df)

KeyWords                                                                         
revenue, apple, inc., aapl, reported
...
```

N.B. The rows of the final dataframe are not lists, but single text values, e.g. revenue, apple, inc., aapl, reported, **NOT**, [revenue, apple, inc., aapl, reported]

Comment: Can you give us the input dataframe?

Comment: it is the column printed at the beginning ( df.tokenized_sents ), the other columns are not relevant for this purpose;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `df.apply`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
tokenized_sents = [['apple', 'inc.', 'aapl', 'reported', 'fourth', 'consecutive', 'quarter', 'record', 'revenue', 'profit', 'combination', 'higher', 'iphone', 'prices', 'strong', 'app-store', 'sales', 'propelled', 'technology', 'giant', 'best', 'year', 'ever', 'revenue', 'three', 'months', 'ended', 'sept.'], 
                   ['brussels', 'apple', 'inc.', 'aapl', '-.', 'chief', 'executive', 'tim', 'cook', 'issued', 'tech', 'giants', 'strongest', 'call', 'yet', 'u.s.-wide', 'data-protection', 'regulation', 'saying', 'individuals', 'personal', 'information', 'been', 'weaponized', 'mr.', 'cooks', 'call', 'came', 'sharply', 'worded', 'speech', 'before', 'p…']

]

df = pd.DataFrame({"tokenized_sents": tokenized_sents})
final_df = pd.DataFrame({"KeyWords" : df["tokenized_sents"].apply(lambda x: [k for k, v in Counter(x).most_common(5)])}) 
#or
#final_df = pd.DataFrame({"KeyWords" : df["tokenized_sents"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(k for k, v in Counter(x).most_common(5)))})
print(final_df)
```

**Output:**

```
                               KeyWords
0  [revenue, apple, aapl, sales, ended]
1   [call, saying, apple, issued, aapl]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have it not in the form of a list, but as a single string: revenue, apple, aapl, (...)?  I tried with final_df.KeyWords.map(lambda x: x.lstrip('[]')) but it doesn't work @Rakesh

Comment: `final_df = pd.DataFrame({"KeyWords" : df["tokenized_sents"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(k for k, v in Counter(x).most_common(5)))})
`

Comment: Perfect, please add it to the answer and I will accept it straight away; Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you can change the return format, but you could use apply and lambda to re-format the columns. E.G. 
`df = pd.DataFrame({'wrds':[[('revenue', 2), ('apple', 1), ('inc.', 1), ('aapl', 1), ('reported', 1)]]})`

`df.wrds.apply(lambda x: [item[0] for item in x])`

returns just the list of words `[revenue, apple, inc., aapl, reported]`

Answer (score 0):

**Something like this? Using** [**`.apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
# creating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"token": [['apple', 'inc.', 'aapl', 'reported', 'fourth', 'consecutive', 'quarter', 'record', 'revenue', 'profit', 'combination', 'higher', 'iphone', 'prices', 'strong', 'app-store', 'sales', 'propelled', 'technology', 'giant', 'best', 'year', 'ever', 'revenue', 'three', 'months', 'ended', 'sept.'], ['brussels', 'apple', 'inc.', 'aapl', '-.', 'chief', 'executive', 'tim', 'cook', 'issued', 'tech', 'giants', 'strongest', 'call', 'yet', 'u.s.-wide', 'data-protection', 'regulation', 'saying', 'individuals', 'personal', 'information', 'been', 'weaponized', 'mr.', 'cooks', 'call', 'came', 'sharply', 'worded', 'speech', 'before', 'p…']
]})
# fetching 5 most common words using .apply and assigning it to keywords column in dataframe
df["keywords"] = df.token.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(i[0] for i in Counter(x).most_common(5)))
df
```

Output:

```
    token   keywords
0   [apple, inc., aapl, reported, fourth, consecut...   revenue, apple, inc., aapl, reported
1   [brussels, apple, inc., aapl, -., chief, execu...   call, brussels, apple, inc., aapl
```

**Using `for` loop** [**`.loc()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) **&** [**`.itertuples()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"token": [['apple', 'inc.', 'aapl', 'reported', 'fourth', 'consecutive', 'quarter', 'record', 'revenue', 'profit', 'combination', 'higher', 'iphone', 'prices', 'strong', 'app-store', 'sales', 'propelled', 'technology', 'giant', 'best', 'year', 'ever', 'revenue', 'three', 'months', 'ended', 'sept.'], ['brussels', 'apple', 'inc.', 'aapl', '-.', 'chief', 'executive', 'tim', 'cook', 'issued', 'tech', 'giants', 'strongest', 'call', 'yet', 'u.s.-wide', 'data-protection', 'regulation', 'saying', 'individuals', 'personal', 'information', 'been', 'weaponized', 'mr.', 'cooks', 'call', 'came', 'sharply', 'worded', 'speech', 'before', 'p…']
]})
df["Keyword"] = ""
for row in df.itertuples():
    xount = [i[0] for i in Counter(row.token).most_common(5)]
    df.loc[row.Index, "Keyword"] = ', '.join(i for i in xount)
df
```

Output:

```
    token   Keyword
0   [apple, inc., aapl, reported, fourth, consecut...   revenue, apple, inc., aapl, reported
1   [brussels, apple, inc., aapl, -., chief, execu...   call, brussels, apple, inc., aapl
```